# Error al enviar formulario con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario con un textarea por ajax para luego recibir los datos con PHP para poder registrarlo en la base de datos, pero el problema esta en que no me llega nada *publication.php*
He colocado un **var_dump()** para ver si me esta llegando algo por POST[] pero no me esta llegando nada, sin embargo si esta llegando a *publication.js* donde esta el ajax para enviar por POST los datos que recibirá **php**

**Formulario:**

```
<form method="POST" class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <!-- <i class="material-icons prefix">photo_camera</i> -->
                                <textarea id="post" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
                                <label for="post">Dile algo al mundo...</label>
                                <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">

                                <div class="file-field input-field">
                                    <span class="file-path-wrapper">
                                        <i class="material-icons prefix">photo_camera</i>
                                        <input id="img" type="file">
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Boton de publicar -->
                            <button class="btn waves-effect btn-color right" type="button" id="public">Publicar
                                <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
                            </button>

                            <p id="respuesta" class="red-text"></p>
                        </form>
```

**Archivo *publication.js* donde esta el ajax:**

```
$('#public').click(function(){

    var post = document.getElementById('post').value;

    // Enviar las variables a la ruta
    var ruta = "post="+post;

    $.ajax({
        url: './backend/publication.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ruta,

    })

    .done(function(res){
        $('#repuesta').html(res)
    })

    .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
    })

    .always(function(){
        console.log(post);
    });

});
```

**Archivo *publication.php* donde esta la logica de PHP:**

```
<?php

// Obtener direccion ip del cliente
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Obtener el navegador del visitante
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$errors = '';

if(isset($_POST['post'])){

    $post = $_POST['post'];

    var_dump($post);

    // Limpiar
    $post = htmlspecialchars($post);
    $post = trim($post);
    $post = filter_var($post, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // Si no hay errores, guardamos la pub en la BD
    if($errors == ''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO publication (id_pub, id_user_pub, messenger_pub, photo_pub, ip_pub, browser_pub, create_at_pub) VALUES(
            null, :id_user, :post, :photo, :ip, :browser, NOW())'
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':id_user' => $id_user,
            ':post' => $post,
            ':photo' => $photo,
            ':ip' => $ip,
            ':browser' => $browser
        ));

    }

}
```

[image: Se muestra como el formulario es enviado con exito, pero no llega a la logica de php]

Si notan, la información esta recogida de forma correcta, pero no se porque razón no me la esta mandando a la url, porque no me esta llegando nada a la pagina *publication.php* donde esta la logica de PHP para guardar la información en base de datos.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar el problema ?

Comment: Sii, ya esta solucionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error se debo a que no estaba llamando a

```
.done(function(res){
        $('#repuesta').html(res)
    })
```

Hay que crear un  dentro del formulario para poder enviar los errores por allí, además que si no lo colocas así no funcionara.

Esta pregunta ya fue solucionada.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer hay algunos errores de *sintaxis* aquí el correcto:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../backend/publication.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ruta
})
```

Se eliminó la ultima coma después de la variable `ruta`, y al parecer aquí te faltó un punto `../backend/publication.php`.

Pruébalo.

Comment: No ha funcionando. Cuando le pongo un punto a `'../backend/publication.php',` me lanzar un error 404 y si le dejo solo un punto y quito la coma al final de *data: ruta* sigue igual que antes sin darme error y sin funcional

Comment: @BraylinIvanPayano si quieres acceder a una carpeta que esta fuera sí se usan los dos puntos para indicar que quieres salir de la carpeta actual porque ingresarás a otra que está afuera, en este caso `backend`.

Comment: Ingresa al fail?

Comment: En que carpeta se encuentra este archivo? y la carpeta `backend` donde la tienes ubicada?...  me imagino que tienes esta estructura:  `carpeta_actual -> aqui está este archivo`...... y en el mismo nivel se encuentra la carpeta `backend->publication.php` que contiene el archivo al que quieres ingresar, por lo tanto para poder acceder a ella tienes que hacer el uso de los dos puntos junto con la ruta al archivo, en este caso: `../backend/publication.php`, mi pregunta es, así está tu estructura de carpetas?

Comment: Y por alguna razon hay algún error en ajax,  imprime lo que te lance el `fail` así: .fail(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })      Checa qué error manda

Comment: La ruta esta enlazada correctamente, lo que entiendo es porque no me estan llegando los datos por POST[] a esa ruta que le estoy definiendo. En la imagen puedes ver el estado 200 que indica que la ruta es correcta, y me funciona solo con colocar un puto en `'./backend/publication.php'` https://ibb.co/9hbtTZ6

Comment: Hice incluso un `var_dump()` para ver lo que me esta llegando por POST[] y no me esta llegando nada

Comment: Ya imprimiste lo que te manda el `fail()`? Que error te muestra `fail(function(data){ console.log(data); }) `

Comment: Prueba el `fail` así como te lo puse, tal vez ahí aparezca el motivo, yo siempre checo ahí los errores para solucionarlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119401/discussion-between-braylin-ivan-payano-and-valle50).

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando jquery podrias intentar cambiar esto:

```
$('#public').click(function(){

var post = document.getElementById('post').value;

// Enviar las variables a la ruta
var ruta = "post="+post;

$.ajax({
    url: './backend/publication.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ruta,

})

.done(function(res){
    $('#repuesta').html(res)
})

.fail(function(){
    console.log("error");
})

.always(function(){
    console.log(post);
   });
});
```

Por esto:

```
$('#public').click(function(){

var post = $('#post').val();

// Enviar las variables a la ruta
var ruta = "post="+post;

$.ajax({
    url: '../backend/publication.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ruta,
    success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response){
       console.log(response.responseText);
    }
 })
};
```

mira la consola y comenta el error que aparece, saludos!